# unmet dependencies on MATE 15.04

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I'm trying to install software for my contour roam2 camera. They don't support Linux so I'm trying to install this http://vulcho.com/contourconfig/#install-contourconfig
then I get this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 contourconfig : Depends: python-launchpad-integration but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-desktopcouch-records but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install them but after it still says same thing
Am I completely out of luck or it there a way to install?
I also tried to install the official software through wine and it wouldn't detect the camera.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
running Ubuntu mate 15.04.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy  contourconfig python-launchpad-integration python-desktopcouch-records`

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer in progress

First start

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to repair if possible

Now start the installation explicit

```
sudo apt-get install python-launchpad-integration python-desktopcouch-records
```

If there more problems, update your question with the error messages and give me a comment.